# Is inline/block Javascript executed before document-ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

Assuming one has inline Javascript code in a HTML document (the body for example), is this piece of Javascript always executed before JQuery document-ready code?

For example, is the following safe?

```
...
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = 2;
   </script>
   ...
</body>

...
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('My Var = ' + myVar);
}
```

If not, how can I make it safe knowing `myVar` is defined in an inline/block code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the above code is safe. Inline JS is executed as it is encountered while the document is being parsed top to bottom. The document ready handler is executed when the document is ready (obviously), and it won't be ready until the whole document has been parsed *including* inline scripts.

Note that you don't really need a document ready handler if you include the code that it wraps as the last thing in the document body, because at that point not only will other inline JS have executed but all of the document elements will have been added to the DOM and thus be accessible from JS.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, inline JavaScript is executed while the HTML is parsed.

It's safe to do that, as long as you don't try to get a reference to a DOM element that wasn't parsed yet (i.e., any element after the script block in the HTML soure code). You can also reference any variable defined on earlier script blocks (as long as they are in scope).

And, as Matt Browne pointed out in his comment, it's also generally safe not to use a DOMContentLoaded listener (or the oldIE workaround, or window.onload) if you put your script that relies on the DOM being loaded right before the closing `</body>` tag. At that point, all HTML elements will be in the DOM already (unless you have further elements after `</body>`, which would be invalid HTML).

Comment: A related note: It's also generally safe not to use `$(document).ready()` if you put your script that relies on jQuery right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: A note about the note: script that relies on jQuery can be anywhere after inclusion of jquery.js. But we know what @MattBrowne meant: script that relies on the DOM being ready can be placed at the end of the body rather than in a ready handler.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to assume that `myVAr` is accessible from within the `$(document).ready(function() {})`.

If you run the code in your HTML, `myVar` becomes a property of the `window` JS global object (i.e. `window.myVar`). I don't think it is necessary to create it locally in the jQuery function.